# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Razor Form, Post not reaching Controller

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I spent a good margin of time searching and working through this problem yesterday without coming up with a solution. [Here is the guide I used as reference.](https://jonhilton.net/2017/08/17/how-to-get-data-from-an-html-form-to-your-asp.net-mvc-core-controller/?fbclid=IwAR3iymMfGeUjOnUu-rIHZv-9TGDGGCWbUQQbwDBnBxibFMxINYVBp-ZLwqo)

The problem is that the data from the form is not reaching my controller. My goal is to take the form data and pass it to my controller/ model so that I can use the values throughout my code and store them in the database. Below is what I have so far...

In my Browse.cshtml (View)

```
@model Collect

<form asp-action="Collect" asp-controller="Collect" method="post">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="GameId" name="@game.id"/>
<button type="submit" class="dropdown-item btn btn-block">Default</button>
</form>
```

In my CollectController.cs (Controller)

```
using System;
using GameLibrary.me.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace GameLibrary.me.Controllers
{
public class CollectController  : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Collect()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Collect(Collect model)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("**********\n"+model.GameId+"\n**********");

        return Content($"Hello {model.GameId}");
    }    
  }
}
```

In my Collect.cs (Model)

```
namespace GameLibrary.me.Models

{
public class Collect
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Here is what my IDE is telling me...

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
  Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:5001/browse?game=eevee application/x-www-form-urlencoded 7

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
  Request finished in 1.0139ms 200

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
  Connection id "0HLJHIUOU6AKO", Request id "0HLJHIUOU6AKO:00000003": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
```

Any guidance on what I am doing wrong would be great appreciated... Also can I send multiple values through the hidden field type, or should I make a new hidden field type for each value?

Comment: what is the value of the GameId hidden input when the page is first rendered? (the linked sample is using non-hidden inputs to gather data, also I believe you'll want to change the name value of your input to just GameId) Also, if you use the broswer debug tools, and look at the POST to your controller, is the GameId value being sent?

Comment: I imagine your routing has an issue because your controller is named Collect, the index method is named Collect, so when the framework is looking for a route your saying it should be `/Collect/Collect`.  You also could use base name of index, like it is searching as a fallback and use `HttpRoute` to predefine a new name.  Unless you correctly defined those custom route names elsewhere.

Comment: I think you're right @Greg ... Just added the response from my IDE to my post. So I would want to change the ASP-ACTION in the razor form and then in my controller change the method name to match?

Comment: @G_P It looks like it is going through. In this case gameID is an int being sent. In this case, if I change this to be a static value such as 5, the same problem occurs. I also just updated my question with the response from my IDE.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your Post controller method, and it gets hit when you debug, then it isn't a routing issue. If it does not get hit, then it is, try renaming the Post method (and updating your form asp-action). Then, if your breakpoint is being hit but the value isn't in your model variable, it is due to model binding not working. Try the rename I of your hidden input I mentioned earlier. Also, to your question about additional values, yes, just add additional hidden inputs if they are values that are needed but should not be edited by the user.

Comment: It looks like you just have a small problem with `name="@game.id"`, which should be `value="@game.id"`, assuming `game` is a variable that's accessible from within your razor view. You shouldn't set `name` at all - the presence of `asp-for` will handle that for you.

Comment: @KirkLarkin thanks kirk, that did resolve the INFO from the IDE "the application completed without reading the entire request body." however, my print statement in my controller still isnt being triggered, even from postman.

Comment: What does the response look like in Postman?

Comment: @G_P I put a break point on my post and ran it through, it's not triggering the break point. I tried changing the asp-action and post method name to Index and then changed both to Test. Still not triggering a break point...

Comment: @KirkLarkin No page found. Please Check your URL.

Comment: Can you inspect the page in your browser developer tools and include the HTML that's being rendered for your form in your question? Alternatively, you might want to consider making your project available in e.g. GitHub (if it's not sensitive).

Comment: @KirkLarkin here is the form



    <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Collect" method="post">
                                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="GameId" value="102873">
                                                <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item btn btn-block">Default</button>
                                            </form>

Comment: That's the problem then. The tag-helpers aren't running. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2#managing-tag-helper-scope).

Comment: @KirkLarkin fixed that issue. The form shows correctly now. Thank you! Though now I am back to:

Connection id "0HLJHLIES6H1B", Request id "0HLJHLIES6H1B:00000002": the application completed without reading the entire request body.

Here is the HTML for reference:

https://www.screencast.com/t/W2dzd6CCn0UF

Lol, I can't believe that the helper tags was a part of the issue. Such a simple fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a lot of different help here, thanks especially to Kirk Larklin! There were three issues that was preventing my controller from picking up the data.

1. Browse.cshtml was missing the @addTagHelpers... I added the following:

   ```
   @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
   @addTagHelper *, AuthoringTagHelpers
   ```
2. My CollectController.cs was missing a route... I added the following:

   ```
   [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   [Route("Index/Collect")]
   ```
3. Finally, I renamed my controller post method from 'Collect' which conflicting with another method to Index and updated the asp-action in my Browse.CSHTML file to match.

   ```
   public IActionResult Index(Collect model)
   ```

Thanks for all the help!

-Travis W

Comment: You did the custom `Route` definer I mentioned, I assume that fixed?

Answer (score 2):

First I would pass in the model to the view with the Id initialised:

```
    public IActionResult Collect()
    {

        return View(new Collect { GameId = "5"});
    }
```

Inside your view update the form to the following:

```
<form asp-action="Collect" asp-controller="Collect" method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GameId)
    <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item btn btn-block">Default</button>
</form>
```

The Html helper will create the html coded for the field. Once you click submit the value will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I updated the login view with this line of code. that's fixed.

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="account" asp-action="login">
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example I do not believe that you want custom actions, you should be able to achieve your goal with the default framework mapping.

```
public class CollectController : Controller
{
     [HttpGet]
     public IActionResult Index() => View();

     [HttpPost]
     public IActionResult Index([FromBody]CollectionModel model) => Content(...);
}
```

To clarify the magic, the declared Post method I utilize a `HttpBody` attribute, otherwise the framework will expect the parameter contents to be defined via Query String in the URL.  The framework by default looks for `Index` when a Controller has been hit, if you do not need the URL to represent that, then do not use it.

The routing pattern usually follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                         // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",      // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

URL:

http://www.sample.com/Collect ---> Initial index Get would be hit